# users' with id='admin' not found angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm facing an issue with an Angular HTTP request that's failing when trying to retrieve data from a specific API endpoint. The request works fine in Postman and functions as expected when using different controllers on the backend. However, when I use the following code to trigger the request in Angular, I encounter an error:

```
loadUserList(page?: number, itemsPerPage?:number): Observable<PaginatedResult<IUser[]>>{
const paginatedResult: PaginatedResult<IUser[]> = new PaginatedResult<IUser[]>();

let finalUrl = this.baseUrl + 'api/users/admin/list';
console.log('finalUrl', finalUrl);

return this.http.get<PaginatedResult<IUser[]>>(finalUrl).pipe(
  map(response =>{
    paginatedResult.dataList = response.dataList;
    paginatedResult.pagination = response.pagination;

    return paginatedResult;
  }),
  catchError(error => {
    console.log('error', error);
    throw error;
  })
);
}
```

The error message I'm receiving is

> "'users' with id='admin' not found"
> [image: error]

Comment: Is "finalUrl" correct? Have you copied that and tried it in Postman?

Comment: yes... finalUrl is correct.  @Rob

Comment: what about header ? Are there anything special headers required from the api?

Comment: @shuvo is this request made with some user identity? perhaps this user is not permitted to access 'admin'?

Comment: To me the strange part is "users with ID admin" - why does it call that an ID? This might be a stretch but is that API running on your localhost on a different port number from your local angular app? Angular sometimes calls URL tokens an ID which is why I ask.

Comment: BùiAnhKhoa,
Benny,    
There are no extra headers or anything else. I tried removing authorization from the controller but still received the same error. However, when I changed the URL from USERS to USER it worked. I am unsure of what is wrong with the provided URL.

Comment: @ChrisBarr
Based on my observation, it seems that this URL recognizes the users and treats admin as a parameter. "Users" is the controller name. Interestingly, everything works fine as long as "users" is not used; if I replace it with anything else, it works fine. For instance, let finalUrl = this.baseUrl + 'api/anything/admin/list'; works perfectly.

Comment: I think you need to debug the API endpoint - it looks like an error from your API 
given it has "body" in the response so maybe your angular code is making a successful request. If you can't put a debugger on it - maybe test adding responses directly after the request with the parameters being passed as the body of the response to confirm it's working as expected. The error looks like it's saying you're trying to get a list of users with "id" = "admin" and there aren't any in your database...